# How can I improve the plot of a picture using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I am trying to display a picture from an url using the Matplotlib module but the problem is the following :

When I execute the code the picture has not a good quality.

Here is my code :

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
picture_url = "https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"

response = requests/get(picture_url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
ax.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. The images seems to match. [This](https://imgur.com/a/AEATXhl) is what I see

Comment: Also works properly for me and I get the same result as the image from @user8408080

Answer (score 0):

While some would say this is the type of answer only a 10x engineer could answer, in this case it only took a 2x!

Try this URL:

https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

The difference is in the "2x" in the URL, which provides a larger png!

Comment: OP complains about the **out**put quality, not the **in**put quality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the axes is not precisely as large as the image, the image will be interpolated. This results in little artifacts.

You can calculate the figure size and margins such that the image fits exactly into the axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


picture_url = "https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
response = requests.get(picture_url)
img = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))

dpi = 100
bottom=0.2; left=0.1; right=0.9; top=0.9
width = img.shape[1]/(right-left)/dpi
height= img.shape[0]/(top-bottom)/dpi
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=dpi, figsize=(width, height))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=bottom, left=left, right=right, top=top)
ax.imshow(img)
fig.savefig("googlelogo.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]